# Retrieve a list of date from a SQL query

Tags: list, date, ebean

Is it possible to retrieve a `List<Date>` instead of a `List<SomeBean>` using Ebean ?

For example, I have this model:

```
Days(id, name, day);
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
List<Date> dates = Ebean.createQuery(Date.class, "SELECT day FROM days").findList();
```

Of course, this doesn't work and returns this:

> PersistenceException: java.util.Date is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?

How can I do that?

Comment: You probably need to edit your question..."Is it possible to retrieve a List instead of a List..."???

Comment: In fact it was a wrong display, I added the code markdown to show them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **sqlQuery** see [SqlQuery in Ebean](https://ebean.io/docs/query/sqlquery) :

> The database retrieves time and date data with a type LocalDateTime

```
String sql = "select day from days";
List<SqlRow> row = DB.sqlQuery(sql).findList();
List<LocalDateTime> days = row.stream().map(r->(LocalDateTime) r.get("day")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```